# Flutter: Why can't I use an Image in an AlertDialog?

Tags: flutter, button

I just want to put an `Image`and an `Text`in this `AlertDialog`, but the Imagename `images/jonglieren.jpg` is red underlined. The shown "Error: The getter 'images' isn't defined for the class 'MyHomePage'" doesn't help too. Here's the `function`:

```
void inform() {
      showDialog<AlertDialog>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              actions: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Jonglieren'), Image.asset(images/jonglieren.jpg)
                  ],
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image path should be a string(it should be in a quotation)

from images/jonglieren.jpg to 'images/jonglieren.jpg'

```dart
void inform() {
      showDialog<AlertDialog>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              actions: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Jonglieren'), Image.asset('images/jonglieren.jpg')
                  ],
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, such an easy solution. But now there is a new problem, when i click the button (witch the AlertDialog is for) Error "Unable to load asset: images/jonglieren.jpg". I have the asset in the pubspec file so thats not the problem.

Comment: Post your pubspec and also let's see the image path In your IDE

Answer (score 0):

The `Image.asset` constructor takes a `String name` as its parameter. So to solve this issue just give your asset path as a String.

```dart
void inform() {
      showDialog<AlertDialog>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              actions: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Jonglieren'), Image.asset('images/jonglieren.jpg')
                  ],
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, such an easy solution. But now there is a new problem, when i click the button (witch the AlertDialog is for) Error "Unable to load asset: images/jonglieren.jpg". I have the asset in the pubspec file so thats not the problem.